# Detect human in proximity?

Tags: sensors, sensor-fusion, ultrasonic-sensors

I'm looking for ways to detect human presense behind walls in close proximity (around 10 feet) in whatever way possible! Problem is I can't code! (I hope it's ok I'm posting here.) 
I know there are different sensors but they all seem to be for detecting by motion of target humans. 
How do you detect still persons?
Is there a sound amplification device that magnifies human breathing x 20?
Or detect body heat?
Or pick up radiation waves or something off humans?

Answer (score 0):

The idea and research of through-wall imaging with uwb radar system has been around for many years.

Saw a product demonstration in technology exhibition recently. The display was a 'wave pattern' that needs 'human interpretation', rather than a layman-clear display as in marine radar polar display.

Try search
[here](https://www.google.com/search?q=through-wall%20imaging%20with%20uwb%20radar%20system&safe=off&biw=1252&bih=534&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=aov1VI-NI-avmAXxw4HoCQ&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAg)

Similarly, ground penetration radar has been a more on-going field application product

Try search
[here](https://www.google.com/search?q=ground%20penetrating%20radar&safe=off&biw=1252&bih=534&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=b4z1VLKaEITQmwXszoCQBg&sqi=2&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAw)

Unlike time-proven and field operational civilian radars (ship, sea-port traffic, airport and weather) where the target signal is significantly stronger than background reflections, human reflection inside a room that is much larger than human body and may have metal objects that reflect strongly, is, in most cases, weaker than background.

If human moves, there is changes, before-and-after the move and can be 'seen' on the 'wave pattern' display by trained operator.

There are research paper [here](http://macau.uni-kiel.de/receive/dissertation_diss_00010153) use filtering to get weak human breathing motion signal from noisy background.

Answer (score 0):

A static human is well shielded by a wall.  Very long wave IR may pass a diffuse heat signature. The sound of breathing or exhaled CO2 may locate someone hiding in a wardrobe.

Micropower Impulse Radar or similar modern implementations for occupancy sensors that are used for turning on lights may work through walls a little but I believe they are Doppler based so need to have movement to detect a person.

The following light fitting incorporates a person sensor and they work through doors, operate at 5GHz and have a ~12mm long antenna on a shielded electronics module inside.

http://www.sahkonumerot.fi/4207001/doc/installationinstruction/